# How to change toast notifications content dynamically while it is displayed in Windows 10

Tags: windows, notifications, toast

I would like to popup a "Downloading..." notification with a progress bar, or at least with a dynamically changing percentage.

Is it possible to change a toast notification content while it is displayed (for windows)?

Answer (score 0):

The [Burnt Toast](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) Powershell Module supports the use of progress bars in Toast notifications. To do so, use the `New-BTProgressBar` cmdlet to get the progress bar as an object, and pass it to `New-BurnToastNotification` with the `-ProgressBar <AdaptiveProgressBar>` parameter:

Example usage taken from the [Burnt Toast documentation](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/blob/master/Help/New-BurntToastNotification.md#---------------------------example-6---------------------------)

```
$Progress = New-BTProgressBar -Status 'Copying files' -Value 0.2
New-BurntToastNotification -Text 'File copy script running', 'More details!' -ProgressBar $Progress
```

Burnt Toast also supports the use of updating notifications by way of removing the old Toast notification and creating a new one. To do this, you need to specify the `-UniqueIdentifier <String>` parameter, making sure to use the same unique ID when creating the updated Toast notification:

Example usage taken from the [Burnt Toast documentation](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast/blob/master/Help/New-BurntToastNotification.md#---------------------------example-7---------------------------)

```
New-BurntToastNotification -Text 'Professional Content', 'And gr8 spelling' -UniqueIdentifier 'Toast001'
New-BurntToastNotification -Text 'Professional Content', 'And great spelling' -UniqueIdentifier 'Toast001'
```